# send automatic mails once a week VBA

Tags: excel, vba

I have the bellow code to send automatic mails when some elements of my database are about to end ( 2 months before the ending dates), however I want the mails to be send once a week is there possible ?
How can I do that ?
Thanks for your suggestions

```
   Dim Desti As String, Objet As String, Corps As String, olApp As Object
Sub AlertesDatesFormations() ' Formations externes
Dim Sh As Worksheet, Chaine As String, Lig As Integer, Alerte
Set olApp = CreateObject("Outlook.application")
Lig = 15 ' car les dates de validité se trouvent en ligne 15
For Each Sh In ActiveWorkbook.Sheets
If Sh.Range("A10") = "Formation externe " Then 'Formation concernée
Col = 2 ' car la premiére date de validité en en colonne B
While Sh.Cells(Lig - 5, Col) <> "" ' on regarde toutes les formations dans la colonne A10 (15-5=10)
If Sh.Cells(Lig, Col) <> "" And Sh.Cells(Lig, Col) < Date + 60 Then ' si formation et date
' on enrichit la chaine avec nom-date-formation
Chaine = Chaine & Sh.Name & vbTab & " Date: " & Sh.Cells(Lig, Col) & " " & Sh.Cells(Lig - 1, Col) & vbCrLf
End If
Col = Col + 1
Wend
If Chaine <> "" Then Chaine = Chaine & vbCrLf
End If
Next Sh
If Chaine <> "" Then
'MsgBox(Chaine, , "Alertes sur les dates de validit?formations.")
'  Alerte = MsgBox(Chaine, , "Alertes sur les dates de validitéformations.")
MsgBox Chaine, , "Alertes sur les dates de validité formations."
  Desti = "annabelle.delecour@nexans.com"
  Objet = "Alertes sur les dates de validité des Formations Externes "
  Corps = "Bonjour, ce message est un mail automatique, il vous informe sur la fin de valdité des formations externes, Merci "
  EnvoiMail Desti, Objet, Corps
End If
End Sub
Sub EnvoiMail(Desti As String, Objet As String, Corps As String)
  Dim M As Object
  Set M = olApp.CreateItem(olMailItem)
  With M
    .Subject = Objet
    .Body = Corps
    .Recipients.Add Desti
    .cc = "pascal.deguines@nexans.com;nicolas.debeyer@nexans.com"
    .send
  End With
End Sub
```

Comment: How often are these emails sent today?

Comment: Every time I open my workbook, the emails are sent automaticlay ( its not limited)

Comment: So that means you currently open it less frequently than once a week?

Comment: Every time I open my workbook the emails are sent automatically

Comment: Yup, we're clear on that now. And how does the data in the workbook get updated? Do you update it manually after you've opened the workbook or in some other way?

Comment: The data are uploaded automatically from teh worksheets

Comment: Uploaded where? How is the data in the worksheets themselves refreshed?

Answer (score 0):

You have a concept problem. A macro doesn't run programatically and run only if the excel is open.

The problem to solve is easy, create an automatic task in windows, this task only have to do is open your excel file, in your excel file in vba in the workbookopen event call your macro and then close your file.

STEPS
1.Modify your Excel // VBA thiswoorbook event open call your macro sendmail
2.Create an automatic task weekly in windows this task only have to open your excel file